# How to recover a corrupted external exFAT hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, exfat

This is a 3 TB external Seagate hard drive formatted in Mac's Disk Utility as a single non bootable exFAT partition. It got unplugged from the computer and now the computer is unable to read it.

`sudo gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk4`:

```
gpt show: disk4: mediasize=3000592977920; sectorsize=4096; blocks=732566645
gpt show: disk4: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk4: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk4: Sec GPT at sector 732566644
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2          4         Pri GPT table
        6      76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    76806        250
    77056  732489472      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
732566528        112
732566640          4         Sec GPT table
732566644          1         Sec GPT header
```

Is it possible to recover the hard drive?

Update: I had to unplug and plug the external hard drive back in. It takes about 5 mins for computer to recognize the hard drive. The following screen pops up.
[image]

I ran the first aid from the disk utility app and the operation was successful but it still show the disk as uninitialized.

`diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                GUID_partition_scheme               *3.0 TB     disk4
1:                        EFI EFI                      314.6 MB   disk4s1
2:       Microsoft Basic Data SEA_EXFAT                3.0 TB     disk4s2
```

The hard drive doesn't show up in finder.

`diskutil verifyVolume disk4s2`:

```
Started file system verification on disk4s2 SEA_EXFAT
Verifying file system
File system check exit code is 1
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 1: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: @klanomath is the format correct? I'm new to this.

Comment: Ok, I think I just messed it up. Do you think I can recover the hard drive?

Comment: I'm unable to run verifyVolume.

Comment: I've updated the command output. I don't know why the list command doesn't show the two partitions.

Comment: @klanomath I finally was able to perform the `diskutil verifyVolume disk4s2` command.

Comment: The partitions are there. One is the EFI system partition, and the other is your exFAT partition.

Comment: The exFAT partition doesn't show up in Finder. I'm unable to access it.

Comment: @klanomath I'm in the process of recovering some of the files using TestDisk. It's going very slow. I'll install TeamViewer after it's done.

Comment: @klanomath I installed TeamViewer. What's your email address?

Comment: @klanomath I emailed you with the TeamView id. Is that all you need?

Comment: simply add a comment (at)klanomath after getting a new drive

Answer (score 2):

I think the drive is already unmounted, if not then unmount it and do this

try mounting in read only mode by doing this

```
diskutil mountDisk readOnly /dev/disk2s1
```

Check if the drive is hijacked by the system

```
ps aux | grep fsck
```

If you see your disk there hijacked then use this to kill this process

```
sudo pkill -f fsck
```

You should immediately see your drive at the finder's sidebar.

Comment: What does it look like for the drive to be "hijacked by the system"? Is it `/System/Library/Filesystems/exfat.fs/Contents/Resources/./fsck_exfat -y /dev/rdisk2s1`?

Comment: fsck_exfat is the "FileSystem ChecK for exfat", trying to check the integrity of the drive and automatically repair mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before with my 4TB Seagate external hard drive too. It also takes too long for the system to recognize my disk, and a lot more issues came with it.

If you unplugged your drive without unmounting / ejecting it properly, it could potentially been occupied by some processes such as `quicklookd` in the background, this can potentially cause problems like corruption in the file system or corruption in clusters. But, if you were not making any modifications to your data at the time when you “unexpectedly” unplugged your drive, the data **may not be affected**, it’s just the file system is unrecognizable for your Mac temporarily since it could be broken when you unplugged your drive.

Here’s the trick, it worked like a charm to me every time when I unexpectedly unplugged my drive without properly ejecting it:

```
diskutil list # to see the identifier of your drive
# disk2s1 will be used in this example, replace it with your own drive identifier
sudo fsck_exfat -y disk2s1
```

Comment: I've tried doing this in the terminal but got this error `fsck_exfat: Can't open /dev/rdisk2s2: Resource busy`.