# WD My Passport isn't showing up on the Desktop after disconnecting without ejecting

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I was working on a project straight from my external hard drive today (not good) when suddenly my old MacBook restarted (from overheating, possibly?). When it rebooted, I unplugged my external hard drive as it wasn't showing up on the Desktop, and plugged it back in. But it did nothing. When venturing into Disk Utility, I saw my external hard drive was there, but it was grayed out. I tried mounting/First Aid, but both errored. When showing all devices on Disk Utility, I get [this:

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility showing the WD hard drive]

And, I'm not sure if this is noteworthy but I read somewhere to check if the hard drive shows up under System Report/USB and it does. Any ideas about what to do as I couldn't be less knowledgeable about these types of things?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285865/how-to-recover-a-corrupted-external-exfat-hard-drive If no joy, you may be down to disk recovery software. In future, never use ExFAT for Mac drives, always reformat as GUID/HFS+ before use [APFS for SSDs]. If you need portability to a PC, use a disposable SD card/USB stick with a *copy* of your data.

Comment: So, my external hard drive suddenly reappeared on my desktop and I'm not sure why. I kept it plugged in while trying to figure out a solution, and poof, everything works fine now. Weird. And thank you for the advice @Tetsujin. I'll most definitely make some changes moving forward.